# VM Machine rebooted, can't find how?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, reboot

One of my VM machine was rebooted yesterday, but can't find how & who did it.
In the log I can only find "receiving signal 15, terminated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With vSphere Client you can see every events happened to ESXi vms.

Go into your vm operation system and use `last|less` to check who shutdown your machines.